# Angular on Windows CE6

Tags: jquery, angularjs, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I need to make a website with angular that should also work on windows CE6 and windows mobile.
The default browser on CE seems to be IE6 and is not supported by angular.
Are there other browsers available in CE/Mobile that are supported?
If it would work, will it be fast enough?

Or should I generate everything on the server and only use some jquery where needed?

Comment: You may try ZetaKey browser (HTML5), but otherwise you seem to be lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully expect getting anything Angular-based in CE/IE6 to be a herculean effort.

Like you said, the Angular team doesn't even (officially) support IE7.  I can say, from experience, that you CAN get Angular to work in IE7, but you need to jump through hoops.  For instance, IE7 doesn't even have a JSON parser.  You need to bring one in.

In addition, anything less than IE9 has major performance issues with Angular-based code.  Again, you can work through it, but you really need to make sure the number of bindings (watchers) is to a minimum.

IE6 will be even more difficult to get working and CE hardware is likely so old that Angular would bring it to its knees.

So, to say what I am saying a slightly different way... any app where Angular is very useful is very likely to hobble that enviornment.  That is, a full-blown SPA style site.  If this isn't the type of site you are building, then Angular probably isn't necessary.  I would spare myself the trouble of getting an Angular app working in this antiquated environment and build it a different way.

Also, if you are going with jQuery, make sure to use a 1.x version.  They stopped supporting IE6 in version 2.x.